# multiple iteration for finding shared items in two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following two lists:

```
list1 = [(('diritti', 'umani'), 'diritto uomo'), (('sgomberi', 'forzati'), 'sgombero forza'), (('x', 'x'), 'x x'), ...] ## list of tuples, each tuple contains term and lemma of term

list2 = ['diritto uomo', 'sgombero forza'] ### a small list of lemmas of terms
```

The task is to extract from the `list1` the terms whose lemmas are present in the `list2`. note that one element in `list2` can share the lemma with more than one term in `list1`, so for every item in `list2` I need to find its shared items in `list1`. I tried this code:

```
result = []
for item in list2:
     for x in list1:
            for i, ii in x:
                    if item.split()[0] in ii or item.split()[1] in ii : 
                            result.append(i)
```

This code takes a long time to do the task, can someone suggest another way to do this. Thanks

Comment: What would the desired output be for the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to match the equal lemmas you don't need to split your words and check the membership you can simply use `==` operation within a list comprehension:

```
>>> [item for item, lemm in list1 for w in list2 if w == lemm]
[('diritti', 'umani'), ('sgomberi', 'forzati')]
```

Otherwise by splitting the lemmas and membership checking within `list1`'s lemmas it won't give you any result.